# Get the last week date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vb.net, date, momentjs

Here is my issue:

I have 2 RadDatePickers see below:

```
      <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpTimeOfDayFrom" runat="server" Culture="English (United States)">          
         <DateInput  runat="server" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"></DateInput>  
        </telerik:RadDatePicker>  
     <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpTimeOfDayTo" runat="server" Culture="English (United States)">          
         <DateInput runat="server" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy"></DateInput>  
    </telerik:RadDatePicker>
```

By using JavaScript I want to get the last week date and set it in the rdpTimeOfDayFrom control the issue is the format is:
Mon Mar 09 2015 17:36:58 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

How can I can I set the return date in that format("yyyy/MM/dd") using Javascript? the reason I'm asking is because after I'm doing post back and trying to get what inisde the control it's been display like that:
3/9/2015 12:00:00AM and I need only the date.

Here is my JS Function:

**Using MomentJS**

```
  function SetLastWeekDate(sender, args) {
    var lastWeekDate = $find("<%=btnTimeOfDayLastWeek.ClientID %>");
    var fromDate = $find("<%=rdpTimeOfDayFrom.ClientID %>");
    var toDate = $find("<%=rdpTimeOfDayTo.ClientID %>");
    var today = new Date();
    if (lastWeekDate.get_checked()) {
        fromDate.clear();
        toDate.clear();
        //var lastWeekPeriod = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(),today.getDate() - 7);
        var lastWeekPeriod = moment().subtract(7, 'd').format('l');
        fromDate.set_selectedDate(lastWeekPeriod);
        toDate.set_selectedDate(today);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is easy to do with [MomentJs](http://momentjs.com/)

```
 function SetLastWeekDate(sender, args) {
    var lastWeekDate = $find("<%=btnTimeOfDayLastWeek.ClientID %>");
    var fromDate = $find("<%=rdpTimeOfDayFrom.ClientID %>");
    var toDate = $find("<%=rdpTimeOfDayTo.ClientID %>");
    var today = moment();
    if (lastWeekDate.get_checked()) {
        fromDate.clear();
        toDate.clear();
        var lastWeekPeriod = moment().subtract(7, 'd').format("YYYY/MM/dd");
        fromDate.set_selectedDate(lastWeekPeriod);
        toDate.set_selectedDate(today);
    }
}
```

if you can set the local of moment to a locale that uses `YYYY/MM/DD` as the default date display you can simply call `format('L')`. `L` is a shortcut in Moment to the locale's default date display.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I added the library to my project but for some reason I can't set the selected date after subtracting 7 days. Any suggestions?

Comment: does this work: `toDate.set_selectedDate(today);`? do you get any console errors?

Comment: Here is my code after the change:  var lastWeekPeriod = moment().subtract(7, 'd').format('l');
            fromDate.set_selectedDate(lastWeekPeriod);  and here is my control:  <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpTimeOfDayFrom" runat="server" Culture="English (United States)">          
                                            <DateInput  runat="server" DateFormat="MM/dd/yyyy">  
                                            </DateInput>  
                                </telerik:RadDatePicker>

Comment: please update your question with the new code, instead of a comment, so that you can format it. Do you have any console errors?

Comment: It's not crashing or marker the line of code where I'm using moment.js in red but it's like stepping over it and getting to that line of code: }}}finally{d._mouseUp(c);   then d._restoreFlags(); and then setTimeout(function(){Page_BlockSubmit=false;

Comment: `'YYYY/MM/dd'` is a wrong format as it will output `03/03/Tu`. It should be  `'YYYY/MM/DD'`, see [solution 2 here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28954636/3120193).

Comment: @MichaelP yup you are correct. The OP is using `L` so it will show the correct format for whatever locale he is using

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you need to substract 7 days to the current date.

---

How about :

**Solution 1**, with *vanilla Javascript* :

```
var d = new Date();           // <- Get the current date
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 7);   // <- Substract 7 days
```

Then format it (this part is a bit weird without library) :

```
var year = d.getFullYear(),
    month = ('00' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    day = ('00' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);

var formattedDate = year + '/' + month + '/' + day;
```

Explanation :

- `d.getMonth()` is zero-based so we have to add one
- `('00' + *number*).slice(-2)` is for formatting the number on two digits.

**Solution 2** :

If you often need to do some computation or formatting with dates, consider working with a library like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) or Date.js. That will really simplify the task. For example, substracting seven days and formatting the date to `YYYY/MM/DD` with momentjs looks like that :

```
moment().subtract(7, 'days').format('YYYY/MM/DD');
```